# Does it matter if the app has always the highest density images

Tags: react-native, image-scaling, screen-density

Im building multiple apps in React-native and I know that there its possible to put in multiple images that have a different density. React-native selects them automatically in the  tag. I know for native Android and iOS they do the same.

I get it if you want to have some changes for lower density devices. Maybe a other design of a icon or something like that. But what if you have the 3x and then resize it to a 2x and 1x. Then you have the same image but with a smaller file.

Now my question is does it really matter to add the 2x and 1x if I already have the 3x? I don't see any performance of quality issues with that.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to have the only single image with the highest density. It will work without any issue.

Comment: so you advise to just use the 3x?

Answer (score 1):

I guess (but not sure) it can give a RAM issues with large amount of images shows simultaneously.
Plus a famous android developer says that Android has an issue with downscale big images.

Comment: do you have a source for that or a blogpost or something? I'm very curious.